# passing parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have an index pages with a link_to:

```
<h1> User:</h1>
        @foreach ($user as $user)

            {{link_to("/users/{$user->username}",$user->username)}}
        @endforeach
```

then i have a route:

```
Route::get('/users/{{$username}}', function($username){

        return View::make('show')->with('username',$username);
```

});

Now, if i understand clear, i am passing username as parameter to function, and username is my url, now if i pass parameter to my show view,

```
<body>
    <div>       

        <h1> User:</h1>
            {{$username}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I should be able to see it in my page. Where i am wrong? I can't take a parameter from the url when i use get?
Why i need to do:

```
Route::get('/users/{{$username}}', function($username){
$user=User::whereUsername($username)->fist();

        return View::make('show')->with('username',$user);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route is wrong, this is the correct one:

```
Route::get('/users/{username}', function($username){

    $user=User::whereUsername($username)->fist();

    return View::make('show')->with('user',$user);

});
```

It's just

```
/users/{username}
```

and not

```
/users/{{$username}}
```

Also, you view will receive an user object, so you have to:

```
 <div>       
     <h1> User:</h1>
         {{$user->username}}
 </div>
```

**EDIT**

In Laravel there are 2 kind `{}`:

1) In views you have to use `{{}}` or `{{{}}}` (escaped version). Inside them you put PHP code:

```
{{$variable}}

{{ isset($variable) ? $variable : 'default value' }}
```

2) In routes, you just use `{}` and inside it it's not PHP, just a route parameter name, without `$`:

```
/user/{name}

/user/{id?} (in this case id is optional, might or might not be send)
```

Comment: Thank you a tons, it's clearer now, i have mistaken the path in route for a variable, instead is a parameter that comes from a variables in this case but is just a plain text i pass to route